# How can rebasing simulate a fast-forward in a non-fast-forward merge?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, rebase, git-rebase

The [bitbucket documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/git-fast-forwards-and-branch-management-329977726.html) says:

> A non-fast-forward merge is a merge where the master branch had intervening changes between the branch point and the merge back to the master.  In this case, a user can simulate a fast-forward by rebasing rather than merging. Rebasing works by abandoning some commits and creating new ones.

Let's say we have a non-fast-forward merge:

```
- o - o - o - H - A - B - C   <-- master (HEAD)
               \
                P - Q - R   <-- origin/master
```

According to the above quote from the bitbucket documentation rebasing can simulate a fast-forward. However by executing the commands:

```
git checkout master
git pull --rebase
```

`git rebase` which is called by `git pull --rebase`, just takes the commits in the branch master that was checked out and adds them to the new base which is origin/master, resulting in:

```
- o - o - o - H - P - Q - R - A' - B' - C'   <-- master (HEAD)
                          |
                          <-- origin/master
```

A fast-forward (when possible) fast-forwards (i.e. moves forward in time) the master branch's pointer to point to the last commit of the branch that is to be merged. However as shown in the 2nd commit graph rebasing causes HEAD to be at `C'` which is not the same as a fast-forward because as shown in the 2nd commit graph rebasing creates 3 new commits `A'`, `B'` and `C'` instead of fast-forwarding the pointer of the master branch to match the commits that were merged (a fast-forward would cause HEAD to be at `R`).

So how can `git rebase` simulate a fast-forward in a non-fast-forward merge or is that statement from the bitbucket documentation incorrect?

Comment: Rebase **does not fast-forward**, it only *simulates* fast-forward (in bitbucket docs terms; I must say I don't like the word *simulation* here). But certainly nobody expects that rebase fast-forwards. It doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

What will be "fast-forward-like" (after a rebase) is the "git push": `origin/master` will simply be updated to `master` commit locally and on the remote side.
(Assuming no other commits were pushed to `origin` in the meantime by someone else)

```
- o - o - o - H - P - Q - R - A' - B' - C'   <-- master (HEAD)
                          |
                          <-- origin/master

git push

- o - o - o - H - P - Q - R - A' - B' - C'   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

SO the *end result* of a rebase + push would be the same as a fast-forward merge where master would have been *behind* origin/master

```
- o - o - o - H - P - Q - R - A' - B' - C'   <-- origin/master
                          |
                          <-- master (HEAD)

git pull: fetch + fast-forward merge 

- o - o - o - H - P - Q - R - A' - B' - C'   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```